# Pyparsing - Finding Nested Polynomials

Tags: python, regex, context-free-grammar, pyparsing

I'm searching through some algebra and trying to match all expressions of the form:

```
(subexp)^C
```

Where C is an integer and subexp can be one of two things:

a) it can be another expression of the form (subexp)^C
b) It can be an expression of the form var1 op var2 op var3 ... op varn

where a var is of the form letters numbers, such as l2, cd3, hello53, etc.
and an op is either -, *, or +.  This second option can also have terms grouped by parens.

(There is no whitespace, I've just added whitespace above some places for clarity)

So, as an example:

```
(a12 + c33 + d34)^2
(a12 * c33 +-d34)^2
((a12 * c33)^5 + c3)^2
```

etc.

Expressions of this form will be embedded in a line of text.  I need to find all instances of (subexp)^C, and replace them with pow(subexp, C).  In short, I'm trying to convert some computer algebra to functioning C code.

I was originally doing this with regexp, but realized it wasn't a regular expression.  For non-nested cases, the regexp is:

```
line = re.sub(r'\(([a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]+\+?-?\*?)+\)\^[0-9]+', replace_with_pow, line)
```

Here line is the line with the embedded polynomials, and replace_with_pow is the function that does replacement.

Unfortunately, when expressions can become nested, it's a CFG.

I have looked into pyparsing but have found the examples to be, well, difficult to parse, and the documentation lacking.  That seems to be the recommended library though.

Can anyone provide an example script of how to find nested expressions and replace them?  (It can be for a simplified problem if you'd like I can build off it)

EDIT: Update: with pyparsing, I can now parse all nested expressions that have the form { stuff ( ...)^C stuff }, using the following code:

```
closing = pyparsing.Word( ")^" + pyparsing.nums )
thecontent = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums) | '+' | '-' | '*' | ',' 
parens     = pyparsing.nestedExpr( '(', closing, content=thecontent)

thecontent2 = thecontent | parens
parens2 = pyparsing.nestedExpr('{', '}', content=thecontent2)

res = parens2.parseString("{sdf(a + (a + b)^5 + c)asdf}")
```

This brings me to two questions:

a) when I have matched my ^5, the parser consumes it.  How can I extract the ^5?
b) Is there a quick / easy way to do replacement with pyparsing?

Comment: Instead of trying to match nested parenthesis (that is not possible with the re module), you can always evaluate and replace innermost parenthesis first (until there is no more parenthesis).

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you provide an example?  Even if this is possible, I don't think this will work.  If I have, say ( ( x1 + x2) + x3 )^2 as my polynomial, it would find (x1 + x2).  There would be nothing to replace here.  Then, if it tries to find more outer parentheses, it gets ( (x1 + x2).  The parens aren't balanced, so this won't work.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean.  How would my pattern fix the problem I just explained in the above comment?

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  I think there was an error in my specification of the problem.  I have updated it.

Comment: In this case, make `\^[0-9]+` optional in your pattern and use a more general function as replacement.

Comment: I think I just gave you a counterexample to that above...you are going to have to work through a simple example to convince me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nestedExpr` is not really the way to go here, that method in pyparsing is there when the items inside the nested punctuation are not too well-defined.  In your case, you are better of defining your own nesting using pyparsing `Forward()`s. See below:

```
from pyparsing import *

# define arithmetic items
identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
integer = Word(nums)
real = Regex(r'\d+\.\d*')
oper = oneOf("* + - /")

# define arithOperand as a Forward, since it could contain nested power expression
arithOperand = Forward()
arithExpr = arithOperand + ZeroOrMore(oper + arithOperand)
groupedArithExpr = '(' + arithExpr + ')'

# define expression for x^y, where x could be any kind of arithmetic term
powerOp = Literal('^')
powerExpr = (groupedArithExpr|real|integer|identifier) + powerOp + integer
powerExpr.setParseAction(lambda tokens: 'pow(%s,%s)' % (tokens[0], tokens[2]))

# now define the possible expressions for arithOperand, including a powerExpr
arithOperand <<= powerExpr | real | integer | identifier | groupedArithExpr

# convert parsed list of strings to a single string
groupedArithExpr.setParseAction(''.join)

# show how transform string will apply parse actions as transforms
print arithOperand.transformString("x = (4*(1 + 3^2) * a)^10")
print
```

prints `x = pow((4*(1+pow(3,2))*a),10)`

```
arithExpr.runTests("""\
    (a12 + c33 + d34)^2
    (a12 * c33 +-d34)^2
    (a12 * (c33 + c3))^2
    (a12 * (c33 + c3)^4)^2
    ((a12 * c33 + 12)^5 + c3)^2""")
```

prints

```
(a12 + c33 + d34)^2
['pow((a12+c33+d34),2)']

(a12 * c33 +-d34)^2
       ^
Expected ")" (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)

(a12 * (c33 + c3))^2
['pow((a12*(c33+c3)),2)']

(a12 * (c33 + c3)^4)^2
['pow((a12*pow((c33+c3),4)),2)']

((a12 * c33 + 12)^5 + c3)^2
['pow((pow((a12*c33+12),5)+c3),2)']
```

Note the use of transformString above - this will search your source code for matches and splice the modified code back in where the match was found.

Comment: runTests isn't working (transformString is though).  I'm finding this method much simpler than the ply based method, however, I am finding that this is much slower when operating on very long strings.  Is this supposed to be the case?  Is it not optimized for big texts (say, 2MB)?

Comment: pyparsing is not blazingly fast. You may see improvement by turning on packrat parsing (see https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#enablePackrat).  What is the issue with runTests?

Comment: The error is: x = pow((4*(1+pow(3,2))*a),10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 27, in <module>
    print arithExpr.runTests("""\
AttributeError: 'And' object has no attribute 'runTests

Comment: I'm going to accept this though, because this is the route I'm going to go, and I want to open a more specific question as to why a particular parser isn't working for a particular case.

Answer (score 4):

The first step in solving almost any parsing problem is coming up with a precise definition of the syntax to be parsed. If that syntax is context-free, then a context-free grammar is an excellent way of describing it, usually much better than informal descriptions or catalogs of examples.

In this question, your example

```
a12 * c33 +-d34
```

does not fit the description

```
var op var op var ... op var
```

because it has two `op`s side-by-side. And in the example

```
((a12 * c33)^5 + c3)^2
```

the subexp `(a12 * c33)^5 + c3` is not `var op var` either; rather it is `( subexp ) op var`. (I know, your text mentions that "terms can be grouped by parentheses", but fails to mention that the "term" can actually be a `subexp` since it might be an exponentiation, as in your example.)

A more precise grammar might be (if I'm guessing correctly), written in "yacc" syntax:

```
val : IDENTIFIER
    | '(' expr ')'
term: val
    | val '^' INTEGER
    | '-' val
prod: term
    | term '*' prod
expr: prod
    | expr '+' prod
    | expr '-' prod
```

The above does not allow `--var`, `var^I1^I2` nor even `-var^I`. I have no idea from your description whether you would like those to work, but it would be easy to modify. Also, I would have thought that numeric literals would be acceptable, and not just variables, but again that's not mentioned in your problem description (and it would just need to be added to `val`).

You might not actually need to parse so precisely, since you seem to be planning to just generate C code and thus dealing with operator precedence is unnecessary. On the other hand, you may someday wish to do algebraic transforms, in which case the more precise parse is necessary, and in any case it doesn't cost much.

Once you have the grammar, you could use [`ply`](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) (for example) to turn it into an executable parser.

---

(Here's a ply file I threw together. But it's not very good style :( )

```
from ply import lex, yacc
class Lexer(object):
  tokens = ('INTEGER', 'IDENTIFIER')
  literals = '+ - * ( ) ^'.split()
  t_ignore = ' \t\n'
  t_INTEGER = r'[1-9][0-9]*'
  t_IDENTIFIER = r'[a-z]+[0-9]+'

  def t_error(self, t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

  def build(self, **kwargs):
    self.lexer = lex.lex(module=self)

# Parser starts here

tokens = Lexer.tokens
start = 'expr'

def p_unit(p):
  '''val  : IDENTIFIER 
     term : val      
     prod : term    
     expr : prod   
  '''
  p[0] = p[1]

def p_paren(p):
  '''val  : '(' expr ')' '''
  p[0] = p[2]

def p_binary(p):
  '''expr : expr '+' prod
     expr : expr '-' prod
     prod : term '*' prod
  '''
  p[0] = '(%s%s%s)' %(p[1], p[2], p[3])

def p_pow(p):
  '''term : val '^' INTEGER'''
  p[0] = 'pow(%s, %s)' % (p[1], p[3])

def p_unary(p):
  '''term : '-' val'''
  p[0] = '(-%s)' % p[2]

parser = yacc.yacc()
lexer = Lexer().build()
def parse(text):
  return parser.parse(text, lexer=lexer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from sys import argv
  for text in argv[1:]:
    print(text + ' => ' + parse(text))
```

Quick test:

```
$ python exp.py '(a12 + c33 + d34)^2' '(a12 * c33 +-d34)^2'
(a12 + c33 + d34)^2 => pow(((a12+c33)+d34), 2)
(a12 * c33 +-d34)^2 => pow(((a12*c33)+(-d34)), 2)
$ python exp.py '((a12 * c33)^5 + c3)^2'
((a12 * c33)^5 + c3)^2 => pow((pow((a12*c33), 5)+c3), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'm realizing that really all I need to do is match nested expressions of the form ( ... )^(Integer) and replace is with pow( ..., Integer).  I need more help with an example of how to find and replace something using a grammar in pyparsing or a similar tool than an explanation of BNFs (sorry my original specification is a bit sloppy)

Comment: Oh, I just saw the ply you added in.  Let me give this a try!

Comment: Thank you for this.  This seems to do most of what I need.  I will fill out the rest.  Can you explain what's going on here at a high level though so I can understand the code a little better?

Comment: Ply uses docstrings to contain the BNF description of the grammar. Each parsing function is called with an indexable object representing the associated value of each symbol in the production; element 0 is the nonterminal on the left and must be filled in by the function; the reamining elements correspond to the symbols on the right hand side. In my littlw hack, I just put the original operation back together, except for the pow rule